# OSRM - Speed up/down gradient

Tags: osrm

Is it possible in **OSRM**, that I can define in a routing profile, that downhill is speeding up and uphill is speeding down?

And another question:

Is it possible to make the two sides of a street independent?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible using raster elevation data. [Here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/profiles/rasterbot.lua) is an example profile that uses this feature.